# Recognizing IR pattern/possible CRC in code?

Tags: hex, crc, infrared

Short brief: I have a small toy that uses infrared signals from a remote to change colors of some lights, as well as their patterns. I've managed to capture the pattern timings, wrote a script in python to convert it to 1's and 0's, and then I have an android app that will convert the 1's and 0's to the IR timings for the blaster. I've tested all of these patterns and they make the toy respond as expected from my phone.

Instead of trying to capture every single pattern manually, I think there's some sort of patterns inside the codes - I'm trying to figure them out. It looks like there's a check at the end of each, but *that's the part I can't crack*. I've tried simple checksum-like things, as well as revEng.

In all honesty, this is a bit over my head - my experience is mostly web-based. I don't even know for sure if there's a CRC code, but it makes sense looking at the data.

Here are a few samples - I've provided them as the binary as well as translated to HEX (less characters to stare at).

Pattern titles are *Color* / *Animation* / *Transition* / *Speed*

```
Light Blue / Double Flash / Fade / Normal
1001001100111011011010011100101001010010111110100011011001101000001000110100101011010111101111011110111101001011110110101011101100101001
93 3b 69 ca 52 fa 36 68 23 4a d7 bd ef 4b da bb 29



Light Blue / Solid / None / Normal
1110001100110011011011100111101111111010100111001010010100101111001010110001000011110110101001111110101110100011100001101000111110111101111011011001
e3 33 6e 7b fa 9c a5 2f 2b 10 f6 a7 eb a3 86 8f bd ed 90



Light Blue / Pulse / Straight / Slow
10110011001110110110111100101010010111101111011010101001111011111010001100000110110110011010011100101001010010111010101
b3 3b 6f 2a 5e f6 a9 ef a3 06 d9 a7 29 4b aa

Light Blue / Pulse / Straight / Normal
10110011001110110110111100101011001111101111011010101001111011111010001100000110110110011010011100101001010010111101011
b3 3b 6f 2b 3e f6 a9 ef a3 06 d9 a7 29 4b d6



Light Blue / Pulse / Fade / Fast
11100011001100110110111001111010001000101001110010100101001011111010001101100110111110000011011010001011111010111011111010011111101111110110110000001
e3 33 6e 7a 22 9c a5 2f a3 66 f8 36 8b eb be 9f bf 6c 08

Light Blue / Pulse / Fade / Normal
1110001100110011011011100111101010000000100111001010010100101111101000110110011011111000001101101000101111101011101111101010111110111111011011
e3 33 6e 7a 80 9c a5 2f a3 66 f8 36 8b eb be af bf 6c

Light Blue / Pulse / Fade / Slow
1110001100110011011011100111101111000110100111001010010100101111101000110110011011111000001101101000101111101011101111101101011110111111011011101011
e3 33 6e 7b c6 9c a5 2f a3 66 f8 36 8b eb be d7 bf 6e b0
```

You can see that the `Pulse / Fade` patterns all start the same, as well as the `Pulse / Straight` - which makes me believe even more that the entire IR sequence is simply a list of parameters, not necessarily pre-defined patterns.

**tl;dr: Are there CRC patterns at the ends of these, and how can I figure them out?**

Comment: Are you sure that you're not missing a byte at the end of Light Blue / Pulse / Fade / Normal?

Comment: If you can provide several more (e.g. two dozen?) examples of 19-byte messages like the three that are there, I could check to see if that last byte obeys the linearity properties of a CRC.

Comment: @MarkAdler I was speaking to someone about this - the python script that decodes the IR signals cuts off any `0`s at the beginning or the end; I feel like it would make sense that they could be zero-filled to the nearest byte (which is what the hex values essentially did when translated). I do have more, but they are not all the same length. Would you like me to just post a bunch of them?

Comment: The last byte _might_ be an 8-bit CRC or other check value. If it's a CRC, then zero is a possible CRC. In any case, yes, post as many as you have of whatever lengths, and I'll see if I can discern anything about the presence and nature of a check value.

Comment: @MarkAdler thanks! I'll get on that after work today.

Comment: @MarkAdler this is a list of everything I have: http://pastebin.com/nW5cpXdf
I just tested each code and they all made the toy respond as expected.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell anything from the data. There many different bit lengths (most not multiples of eight).

Comment: @MarkAdler dang, thanks for trying!